# influx write command is throwing error: "unsupported protocol scheme"

Tags: export, influxdb, migrate, telegraf, influx-line-protocol

I have exported my data from an InfluxDB bucket with the following command:

```
> influxd inspect export-lp --bucket-id d5f80730ede82d67 --engine-path ~\.influxdbv2\engine --output-path ~\Desktop\my-data.lp.gz --start 2022-11-01T00:00:00Z --end 2022-12-31T00:00:00Z --compress
```

I am following steps from this [influxdb document](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/migrate-data/migrate-oss/).

[image]

The size of the exported file is ~8MB.

I use the below command to write the exported file back to my new bucket:

```
> influx write --bucket my-new-bucket --file ~\Desktop\my-data.lp.gz
```

I am following this [InfluxDB document](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/write-data/developer-tools/line-protocol/#write-line-protocol-from-a-compressed-file) to write my data.
[image]

Now when I try to write it back to the DB, I get an Error:

> Error: failed to write data: Post "/api/v2/write?bucket=my-new-bucket&org=00ef2f123c4706fd&precision=ns": unsupported protocol scheme ""

I have even tried to export and import without compressing and using *.txt* format for my line protocol. Still for all my attempts I face this same error.

I even tried uploading the same exported file through Telegraf > Sources > Line Protocol. But that too fails with an Error:

> Unable to Write Data

> Failed to write data - invalid line protocol submitted.

I don't know why the file exported from InfluxDB's "*export-lp*" command fails when I try to write it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can help , you I have this error. because I no system variable for:
INFLUX_HOST: InfluxDB host URL.-->**export INFLUX_HOST=http://localhost:8086**

[root@Monitor influxdb]# export INFLUX_HOST=""

[root@Monitor influxdb]# influx write --bucket buck01 --precision s "home,room=Kitchen temp=22.7,hum=36.5,co=26i 1641067400"

**Error: failed to write data:** Post "/api/v2/write?bucket=buck01&org=xxx&precision=s": **unsupported protocol scheme ""**

with the variables:
influx write --bucket buck01 **-host "http://localhost:8086"** --precision s "home,room=Kitchen temp=22.7,hum=36.5,co=26i 1641067400"
OK no error

Comment: Thanks, appending the host flag --host http://localhost:8086 worked for me.